# DAS Storage for Ubuntu NAS

Tags: networking, server, hard-drive, nas

I want to use Ubuntu to make a server, if my computer has no HDD bays can I use a DAS connected to the computer as the storage for that server? I would get a DAS that is connected via USB.

Comment: As long as the OS can see it and it can be mounted, it can be used.  I have mounted external USB drives many times to Ubuntu Server.